# Please add a list of failed review audits

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

I apparently failed too many First Post-review audits, and have been banned for two days.

I would like to have a list of audits I failed, so I can try and find some pattern in what I'm doing wrong.

It can be linked from the profile page or the review page.

Comment: You can see a full list of all review activity: http://stackoverflow.com/users/694001/soren-debois?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Thanks, but I can't seem to find the failed audits? I'd expect the "last straw" audit to be the most recent, but it seems to not be there?

Comment: @SørenDebois you asked "is it possible" and the answer is "not really", and was already given thus duplicate. I changed youe question to "Please make such list" instead and voted to reopen as this is a legit request. Good luck! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok, thanks!